# Oauth Jmeter Load testing

Tags: http, jmeter

I am performing the Jmeter load testing. Our application is on Oauth authentication. How can i logging using Jmeter so that we can perform load testing on our application.
Right now we are not able to set parameters on "HTTP Authorization Manager" for login.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use HTTP Authorization Manager, you need to pass the [Bearer token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

With regards to the token value - there are several ways of getting it, they depend on OAuth version and your application configuration, you need to contact your application developers in order to learn how you can obtain the token.

You can also check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for several workarounds listed and explained.